# Retag Request - Korn Shell

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please combine the following tags

- [korn](/questions/tagged/korn): 23
- [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh): 86

Into the [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) tag.

I already removed the one `kornshell` tag.

Comment: You're assuming that korn is referring to the shell rather than the influental Nu-Metal band of the 90s?

Comment: Or to the very popular german spirit? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_%28liquor%29

Comment: @Adamski Since there were no `not-programming-related` tags, yes.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the subject -- which of the two tags do you want to keep?

Comment: @Jon Both are valid, but ksh seems to be more popular so let's go with that (changed the question to say that).

Comment: There are some question with overlapping tags. For example `[ksh]` + `[shell]` + `[korn]`. What would that be reduced to? Just `[ksh]`? Or `[shell]` + `[ksh]`?

Comment: @Jon In my opinion it should go to `shell` + `ksh`.  That's just my opinion though.  Korn shell is such a small community, even on SO, that it's nice to have the general shell scripting community looking at the questions.

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... tag.... `[always-korn-in-iceland]`

Comment: `[always-korn-in-belllabs]`?  I think that breaks the tag size limit though.

Comment: How are you going to display the backwards r in the korn tag?

Comment: @Michael: KoЯn.

Comment: @Gnome - Sweet!

Comment: @Gnome unfortunately it strips out that character when I try to put it in a tag.

Comment: @Gnome: Word (vote) Up!

Comment: This whole thread is just too korny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have completed this request by hand by replacing [korn](/questions/tagged/korn) with [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) + [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) on 24 questions.

Since I'm not familiar with the subject matter, this was just a straight replace -- I didn't do any additional tag auditing. There was only 1 instance of running into the tag limit, but that involved removing one of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (of which I didn't see any in the question) or [string-manipulation](/questions/tagged/string-manipulation), so I left the latter.